# On click of li should open a url in other div but with some data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

i am using django in my project to create a chat for friends(has id's assigned)

the problem is to **load a url(with id and friend.id) generated in for loop**, on click of the **li** element in **second_div** element

something like **master-detail view** in android or consider as full conversation view in facebook

plz help me

```
<div id="first_div" class="col m4 l4 s4">
   <p>Chat with your friends</p>
       <ul>             
       {% for friend in friends %}
     <li><a href="/chat_box/{{ id }}/{{ friend.id }}">{{ friend.name }}</a></li>
       {% endfor %}</ul>
</div>
 <div id="second_div" class="col s8 m8 l8">
<!--the href link to be loa-->
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already setting the id and friend.id for the url.
In your urls.py -

```
url(r'^foo/(?P<id>[^/]+)/(?P<friend_id>[^/]+)/$', views.foo_view, name='foo_view'),
```

in your views.py -

```
def foo_view(request, id, friend_id):
    # do whatever you want with them
```